# SQLite select * query only returning values on first column

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
  List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS;

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
    User user = new User(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6));

    userList.add(user);
   } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }

  return userList;
 }

 public void addUser(User user) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(KEY_ID, user._id); // User id
  values.put(KEY_BLUETOOTH_NAME, user._bluetooth_name);
  values.put(KEY_COLOR, user._color);
  values.put(KEY_LAST_LAT, user._last_lat);
  values.put(KEY_LAST_LNG, user._last_lng);
  values.put(KEY_MODEL, user._model);
  values.put(KEY_LAST_SEEN, user._last_seen);

  db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
  db.close(); 
 }
```

**User class properties**

```
public class User {

String _id;
String _bluetooth_name;
String _color;
String _last_seen;
String _model;
String _last_lng;
String _last_lat;

 public User(String id, String bluetooth_name, String color, String last_seen, String model, String last_lng, String last_lat){
      this._id = id;
      this._bluetooth_name = bluetooth_name;
      this._color = color;
      this._last_seen = last_seen;
      this._model = model;
      this._last_lat = last_lat;
      this._last_lng = last_lng;
 }

}
```

---

```
DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

dh.clearTable(); //clear the table

User user = new User("1","2","3","5","6","7","8"); //add dummy user

dh.addUser(user);

List<User> userlist = dh.getAllUsers(); //all users properties are null, except "id" (which is the first prop, value: "1")
```

Probably an easy question since this is my first attempt at using SQLite in android:

I'm trying to get all the users that I've added to my users SQLite table. But only the first property, "id", on all my users are set. Can anyone please explain why?

Update:

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" +
     KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
     KEY_BLUETOOTH_NAME + " TEXT," +
     KEY_COLOR + " TEXT," +
     KEY_LAST_LAT + " TEXT," +
     KEY_LAST_LNG + " TEXT," +
     KEY_LAST_SEEN + " TEXT," +
     KEY_MODEL + " TEXT" + ")";

  db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);
 }
```

Comment: Please post the constructor for User.

Comment: @Sam Allright, updated question

Comment: Could it be the extra spaces before * in your select?

Comment: @Qben Nope, still only getting the _id property :/

Comment: Are the values null in the database? Maybe it's not the select that's the problem, but rather the insert?

Comment: @nEx.Software I cant inspect my database since my phone isnt rooted.

Comment: Wel... You could use the emulator, or temporarily add a method in your app which copies the database to the sdcard so you can inspect it.

Comment: @Johan : Has the database been created with all of the relevant columns?

Comment: @Johan: please post the code that creates the DB.

Comment: @Arhimed It seems to be returning -1 :). Is there any way to get the sql exception as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine such a scenario: you're developing the DB scheme and at some version the table has only `_id` column. You run the app, so it creates the DB/table. Then you add all the rest of the columns to the table creation code, but since the table has already been created the code is not executed again, so the table remains unchanged. If this theory is true, then reinstalling the app should fix it.

**UPDATE:**

I hope `KEY_ID` is "_id"? If not, please fix. Also the SQL for `KEY_ID` should be:

```
KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
```

**UPDATE2:**

Sorry, my UPDATE section above messed up DB id with your business logic User id. So I'd suggest to use `KEY_UID` ("uid") for business logic User id and `KEY_DB_ID` ("_id") for DB id.

Comment: I get the following insert error: `error code 19: constraint failed`

Comment: @Johan: please check the UPDATE section. Also I don't know how you handle DB scheme migrations, so make sure to uninstall the old version before checking the fixed one.

Comment: Wow, it was the `AUTOINCREMENT` that was the problem. Ive read on the net that it should auto increment by default, so i didnt add it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Johan: please check the UPDATE2 section. Sorry.. :)

Comment: Excellent answer, though adding `AUTOINCREMENT` is not necessary: "A column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will autoincrement." ([SQLite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)) It continues to describe that `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is synonymous with `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Cursor.getColumnIndex(String columnName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) to return the indices of the column to feed into `Cursor.getString(long index)`.

Make sure you do this after your query but before you loop through your results otherwise it will be rather inefficient.

Also you should use [SQLiteDatabase.query(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) rather than raw queries to reduce complexity

*UPDATE*

You should not specifiy a value for KEY_ID column if you want it to autoincrement without declaring AUTOINCREMENT in the column definition